# Raspberry send data via serial USB to Arduino Python

Tags: python, serialization, arduino

Hi I have connected my raspberry to arduino via serial USB and on arduino there is a led that I want turn on if in the script in python I send a letter o a number

I have write this code in raspberry Python:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
ser.write('3')
```

In my arduino I have load this skatch:

```
const int ledPin = 12;
int val;
void setup(){
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  if (Serial.available())  {
     val=Serial.read();
     if(vale==3)
       digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);
  }
  delay(500);
} 
}
```

When I lunch the script py from rasp, I see that led not turn on, but turn on a onboard led of arduino.

I think that the problem is the type of data like ASCII or integer but I don't understand how to fix. 
Serial device is ok and is USB0 and the pin of led on arduino is right
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the if statement, you have put vale instead of val.

```
ser.write('3')
```

takes 3 as a string.So try this in the if statement,

```
if(val=='3')
```

Comment: You are right but in my sketch on arduino the val is ok, only there I have wrong.

Comment: @MassimoMezzina if it doesnt work put time.sleep(5) before ser.write('3'), it often happens that the arduino takes time to open the port and so the input is discarded by the arduino.